# What is the interior, exterior and boundary of $\mathbb{Z} \cup (-\infty, \pi)$

Tags: real-analysis

int ($\mathbb{Z} \cup (-\infty, \pi)) \subseteq$ int $\mathbb{Z}$ $\cup$ int $(-\infty, \pi)$

int $\mathbb{Z} = \emptyset$ and int $(-\infty, \pi) = (-\infty, \pi)$

Hence int ($\mathbb{Z} \cup (-\infty, \pi)) \subseteq (-\infty, \pi)$.

But I need to show equality, not subset. Is there a different approach I should use to get the interior of the set?

Comment: Hint: If $A\subseteq B$ then $int(A)\subseteq int(B)$.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of this rule.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there! Note that $(-\infty,\pi)$ is open and $(-\infty,\pi)\subseteq\Bbb Z\cup(-\infty,\pi).$

Since the interior of $\Bbb Z\cup(-\infty,\pi)$ is the union of all open subsets of $\Bbb Z\cup(-\infty,\pi),$ ththen $(-\infty,\pi)$ is a subset of the interior of $\Bbb Z\cup(-\infty,\pi).$ This proves the reverse of the inclusion you already proved, so by double-inclusion, we have equality.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce the set $Z_{\ge 4}=\{n\in\mathbb Z\mid n\ge 4\}$

And notice that $\mathbb Z\cup(-\infty,\pi)=Z_{\ge 4}\cup(-\infty,\pi)$ and now this union is disjoint, but even better the closures of the two sets are also disjoint.

It means you can work the interior and closure without issues (i.e. union of interiors, union of closures).